# Why don't ensembling, bagging and boosting help to improve accuracy of Naive bayes classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, naive-bayes, bias-variance-tradeoff, ensemble-learning, boosting

> You might think to apply some classifier combination techniques like ensembling, bagging and boosting but these methods would not help. Actually, “ensembling, boosting, bagging” won’t help since their purpose is to reduce variance. Naive Bayes has no variance to minimize.

The above paragraph is mentioned in this [article](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/09/naive-bayes-explained/).

1. How can they say the purpose of these methods is to reduce variance?
2. Naive Bayes has no variance, is it true?

Thanks in advance